# Query statement in get_by_id (ndb, GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine with webapp2 and Python.

I have a `User` model with a `deleted` field:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    last_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    deleted = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=False)
```

I'd like to get a User object by calling `User.get_by_id()` but I would like to exclude objects that have `deleted` field `True`. Is it possible to do this with the normal `get_by_id()` function?

If not, could I override it?

Or should I create a custom class method, smth like `get_by_id_2()` that does a normal `.get()` query like this: `User.query(User.key.id()==id, User.deleted==False).get()`?

Would you reccomend something else instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query is significantly slower than a get, and is subject to eventual consistency. You should probably use the normal get_by_id and check deleted afterwards. You certainly could wrap that up in a method:

```
@classmethod
def get_non_deleted(cls, id):
    entity = cls.get_by_id(id)
    if entity and not entity.deleted:
        return entity
```